# Symfony 2 Entity Validation Callback not being called

Tags: validation, symfony, assert

Could someone help me figure out why my Callback validation method is not being called.

Basically what I need to do is a custom validation with following logic:
- in the form I have 5 fields that if all empty, the form should be valid,
- however if any of the is not empty all of them need to not be empty
(they are used to build a real address on a user profile)

I have followed the doc from: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Callback.html

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository");
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isAddressValid"})
 */
class User extends WebserviceUser implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
...

    public function isAddressValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        //die("I GOT HERE");
        $context->addViolationAt('sna4', 'Frikin validation'!', array(), null);
    }
}
```

The property sna4 is found in the class being extended.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you call isValid() in your controller? code from your controller would help!

Comment: check you add the `use` statement for the `ExecutionContextInterface` class

Comment: @Matteo..... I confirm including the use

Comment: @PMoubed...yes I have called isValid `code` if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) `code`

Comment: The form have a validation_groups?

Comment: In my code, the callback stop working when i define a callback on the form.

Answer (score 4):

The callback annotation require (if any is defined) the validation group associated.

As Example, an entity used in different form context with a validation custom for a specific form:

**The Entity Class:**

```
/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateCommunicationEmail"}, groups={"userProfile"})
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validatePreference"}, groups={"userPreference"})
 */
class AcmePreferences
{

    ....

        public function validateCommunicationEmail(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->getIsCommunicationsEnabled() && ! $this->getAdministrativeCommunicationEmail())
        {
            $context->addViolationAt('isCommunicationsEnabled','error.no_administrative_email_selected');
        }

    }

}
```

**The Form Type:**

```
class AcmePreferencesType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=> 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AcmePreferences',
            'validation_groups' => array('userProfile')
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Matteo, will verify this and get back with an answer asap.

Comment: Apparently it has something to do with the form, as I have just received a bug report that on another form that uses the entity, the validation fails and displays the error. Very strange and don't know the reason why, YET.